# JUnit 4 (WebDriver) on Ubuntu

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ubuntu-12.04, junit4, selenium-grid

I use Junit 4 and selenium WebDriver and Eclipse to run my test on ubuntu.
When i run my test i have this error:

```
> org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found
> in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
```

And when i debug my test it works.
And this is my test:

```
package com.QD2.Login;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;   
import org.junit.*;   
import static org.junit.Assert.*;   
import org.openqa.selenium.*;  
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Login {    

  private WebDriver driver;    
  private String baseUrl;    
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before   public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://localhost:8088/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);   
  } 

  @Test   public void testUntitled() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/QD2/pages/accueil/login.xhtml#loaded");
    //driver.findElement(By.id("login")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login']")).sendKeys("admin");
    //driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("admin");
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginButton")).click();   
  }

  @After   public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    //driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: Where the error happens ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an exemple of : `org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException`

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("input123")); // get the input 
WebElement button= driver.findElement(By.id("btn123")); // this button sends the form
button.click();
element.sendKeys("the cache is already released.."); // error here
```

So i think this come from your `#loaded` that's inside the url

```
driver.get(baseUrl + "/QD2/pages/accueil/login.xhtml#loaded");
```

Try without it and tell me what's up.

---

Update :

Try to use a wait like this  :

```
[...]
WebElement login = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
              .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("login")));
login.sendKeys("admin");
[...]
```

**But normally** a wait will not help since this error happens when you're have changed the source by naviguate to another page or sent the form etc..

Comment: when i tired without #loaded the page das'nt load 
but i use     > Thread.sleep(1000); berof > driver.get(baseUrl + "/QD2/pages/accueil/login.xhtml#loaded"); and it work
thanks you for your help :)